# Spring Boot 2 and method parameter validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I created the following service interface:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated
public interface UserService {

    User create(@NonNull Long telegramId, @NotBlank String name, @NonNull Boolean isBot);

}
```

but the following invocation:

```
userService.create(telegramId, "Mike", null);
```

passes the `@NotNull` validation for `isBot` parameter. How to correctly configure Spring Boot and my service in order to take into account `@NonNull` annotation and prevent method execution in case of `null` parameter?

Comment: Did you try putting the `@Validated` annotation on the actual implementation of the service?

Comment: yes, unfortunately in this case I have the same result

Comment: Just slapping on those annotations won't just work. That only works, out-of-the-box, for controllers as it is backed into the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. To enable it for other beans you will also need to add the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` to have the AOP parts registered doing this.

Answer (score 5):

I played around with this problem for a bit.

Your code looks fine to me: Make sure that the implementation of `UserService` also has the validation annotations present.

Ensure that you allow Spring to create the Bean; it should work as you expect.

## Example

### Service Definition

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
public interface GreetingService {
    String greet(@NotNull @NotBlank String greeting);
}
```

### Service Implementation

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Service
public class HelloGreetingService implements GreetingService {

    public String greet(@NotNull @NotBlank String greeting) {
        return "hello " + greeting;
    }
}
```

## Testcase

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@SpringBootTest
class HelloGreetingServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private GreetingService helloGreetingService;

    @Test
    void whenGreetWithStringInput_shouldDisplayGreeting() {
        String input = "john doe";
        assertEquals("hello john doe", helloGreetingService.greet(input));
    }

    @Test
    void whenGreetWithNullInput_shouldThrowException() {
        assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> helloGreetingService.greet(null));
    }

    @Test
    void whenGreetWithBlankInput_shouldThrowException() {
        assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> helloGreetingService.greet(""));
    }

}
```

Testcases are green for me.

Github: https://github.com/almac777/spring-validation-playground

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints

HTH!

Comment: Thank you very much for solution! Is it possible to get it working with `@Service` annotation?

Comment: Yes. Silly me. Simply add the `@Service` annotation on the implementation (in my case) `HelloGreetingService` and remove the bean. My testcases are still green, after doing this. Updated my code, please see updated post and updated code on github, if required.

Comment: I don't understand why the interface is necessary. The linked baeldung-guide does not use it, and I don't see how it would help spring, which needs to create a proxy or subclass for the Service irrespective of what interfaces the object implements. Is this just the old-but-no-longer-necessary of defining interfaces for every class? Or is there a deper reason that I don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `@Validated` annotation is used on 'class' which method arguments will need to be validated and Spring configuration need to be added

```
@Configuration
public class MethodValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same thing in Implementation class instead interface.
Also can write one global exception like:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalRestException extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
...
...

/**
     * Handle MethodArgumentNotValidException. Triggered when an object fails @Valid
     * validation.
     *
     * @param ex      the MethodArgumentNotValidException that is thrown when @Valid
     *                validation fails
     * @param headers HttpHeaders
     * @param status  HttpStatus
     * @param request WebRequest
     * @return the ApiException object
     */
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Error apiError = new Error(BAD_REQUEST);
        apiError.setMessage("Validation error");
        apiError.addValidationErrors(ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors());
        apiError.addValidationError(ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors());
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
    }
}
```

There are more method that can be override to handle different kind of exception like :

```
/**
 * Handles javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException. Thrown when @Validated
 * fails.
 *
 * @param ex the ConstraintViolationException
 * @return the ApiException object
 */
@ExceptionHandler(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    Error apiError = new Error(BAD_REQUEST);
    apiError.setMessage("Validation error");
    apiError.addValidationErrors(ex.getConstraintViolations());
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work for me because `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is not thrown right now. This is the issue - how to get `MethodArgumentNotValidException` thrown in this case?

Comment: YOu will never get that exception here, because it is part of the service layer. The `MethodArgumentNotValidException` is a specific web binding exception. So the latter will never occur for validation errors on a service.